# Text in relative div displays over absolute div

Tags: html, css

I've a peculiar situation where I have a menu that displays an `position:absolute;` div that should render over other content, but the *text* in the scrollable div below it renders over the menu.

I cannot seem to find the combination of tags which would fix this. adjusting the `z-index` property does along with adjusting the `position` property of the divs

[image]

This below code snippit demonstrates what is going on. What works and what doesn't, I require that the parent div be relative to position the menu icon within its parent div and I'm somewhat at a loss on how to have this render correctly.

```css
.scrollable-r {
 padding-top:12px;
 overflow: auto;
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 position:relative;
}
.scrollable {
 padding-top:12px;
 overflow: auto;
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
}
.menu {
position:absolute;
background:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div>
    Text1
  </div>
    <div>
    text2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="scrollable-r">aasdfafqfgqgqgqgqgqre</div>


<div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div>
      Text1
    </div>
      <div>
      text2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="scrollable">aasdfafqfgqgqgqgqgqre</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the desired result?

Comment: The code snippit with just `scrollable` is the desired result but I require that scrollable be relative which demonstrates the problem. I can adjust the z-index but the content is repeated in a loop so even if I adjust the z-index there will still be content below which would have the same z-index, and will sit over the menu

Comment: Setting z-index on .menu should do the trick

Comment: I figured it out with some help from vue `v-for` index, I dynamically set the z-index to be progressively lower as more divs are rendered, allwing content to be rendered in the propr order;not over one another